# Angular 2 router navigate '../' moves to the root state instaed of the parent

Tags: angular, routes

I have layout: '/home', 2 pages: '/home/sample/list' and '/home/sample/details' and their layout: '/home/sample'. I'm trying to navigate to the parent state from '/home/sample/details' to '/home/sample' and then redirect to '/home/sample/list'. But when I try to use smth like '../' it moves me to the '/home'. What I'm doing wrong?

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent, children: [
       { path: 'sample', component: SampleComponent, children: [
          { path: '', redirectTo: 'list', pathMatch: 'full' },
          { path: 'details', component: SampleDetailsComponent },
          { path: 'list', component: SampleListComponent },
       ]}
    ] },
    { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
];
```

After user click on a button I want to return him to the parent state (like a back button)

```
this.router.navigate(['../']);
```

Comment: Try to use like this, this.router.navigate(['/home/sample']);If you use this.router.navigate(['../']); it will checks for default route and load homecomponent

Comment: With full path like '/home/sample' it works fine. But in my case, back button can be on any page, so I don't really know the path to return. That's why I need the relative one '../'

Comment: For back button navigation you can use window.history.back();

Comment: I wish I could, but it will bring some issues in the future, for example when user just open the website from Google or Bookmarks and in this case it won't work correctly.

Comment: You can check for navigation start event in your app like this   router.events
            .filter(event => event instanceof NavigationStart)
            .subscribe((event: NavigationStart) => {
                console.log(event);
                // You only receive NavigationStart events
            });

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**If you want to do relative routing**

You have to define it by `relativeTo` , this will navigate to the one upper level

```
this.router.navigate(['../', { relativeTo: this.route }]);
```

> `this.route` is `ActivatedRoute`

Comment: What's `this.route` in the example? Do you mean the current state `this.router.routerState`?

Comment: Thanks for the example, I found how to make it works for me.
In the service I put method
       `goLevelUp(route: ActivatedRoute) {
               return this.router.navigate(['../'], { relativeTo: route });
         }`
Then in a component I'm able to call 
         `this.urlService.goLevelUp(this.route);`
And `this.route` I'm just getting in a constrcutor
         `constructor(private urls: UrlService, private route: ActivatedRoute)`